# I am making a mancala game; and need help figuring out how to move the 'marbles' to each hole. Im figuring an if statement is the way to go but lost

Tags: javascript

This is what i have so far. i am able to target the pits and the seeds itself.
My 'seeds' are just a number displayed in the pits.I have not targeted the storage yet so maybe i should define a variable that can. Im able to get the next pits number updated but the ones following do not update

```
   /// event listener to hear pits clicked
    allPits[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        ///  targeting pits indivually but also the seeds amount within
        let currentSeeds = allPits[i].dataset.seed
        // hitting and changing hardcode html-- 4-4=0 
        allPits[i].innerHTML =  allPits[i].dataset.seed - currentSeeds
         
        console.log('clicked:', allPits[i])
        console.log(allPits[i+1])
        ///interating thru the following pits to add a seed
            allPits[i+1].dataset.seed++
        console.log('add', allPits[i+1].dataset.seed)
        //changing the hardcoded 4 to +1 to add to the next pits seed count
        allPits[i+1].innerHTML = allPits[i+1].dataset.seed
        //for loop to finish out the previous code 
        for(let k = 0; k < currentSeeds; k++){
            console.log('currentseeds', currentSeeds)
            //delivers the +1 seed to next pit
            currentSeeds[k] = allPits[i+k]
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: The return value of your moveSeeds function is quite weird. How did you try to use it so far ?

Comment: just to try and diminish the amount of seeds from the pit you are grabbing from to distribute to the following pits one by one-- it is not viable by any means

Comment: Can you describe in words how you move the seeds to the pits?  Start with that.  Pretend you're explaining it to a person who has no idea what's going on or how to play.  That's the level of detail that your program will need to be told also.  It involves picking up all the seeds in one pit, putting them in your hand and then placing them one at a time into successive pits, until your hand is empty.  You will likely need some modular arithmetic.  Do you know how the modulus operator (`%`) works? That will help you "wrap around" the pit index if you use `i % N`.

Comment: I do not but reading up on it would  ```if(i +k = % ``` then some sort of repeating action be what im looking for ?